# Adding UINavigationController functionality to a container controller with a defined Protocol

Tags: ios, xcode, delegates, uinavigationcontroller, protocols

I've designed a custom container view controller that mimics the functionality of something like path or facebook (the sliding deck effect). In order to communicate with those controllers, I've defined a protocol that allows ask them for some info/ alert them to some events.

Now, i've decided I'd like one of these child view controllers to be embedded in a navigation controller. Unfortunately, The navigation controller is now receiving those protocol methods and I'm getting a crash.

My temporary solution is to create an intermediary method that asks whether the controller i want to talk to is infact a navigation controller, and if it is, send the message to the root.

Is there any more graceful way of doing this? It seems like code smell to have to write an 'in between' method that performs this check for every single protocol method in my base controller. Any thoughts??

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried embedding the parent view controller within a NavigationController instead of a specific child controller?  By doing this, you effectively allow all child controllers to participate within the navigation.  This will allow you to properly utilize your protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to set your up your child view controller with a delegate and send its messages to its delegate rather than its parent.

If you don't know about delegates: [Cocoa Fundamentals Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW18)

Comment: wait, but I want to make a call FROM my container TO the child. Isn't creating a delegate for the child going in the wrong direction? I don't see how I can keep this controller flexible while having to keep track of all the separate instances of child controllers.

Comment: Perhaps the best way to do this is to override a getter for the currentChildViewController, and then perform the check for the navigation controller there.

Comment: If that is the case, why can the parent not just hold onto a reference to the child?

Comment: because the child may or may not be a navigation controller